# jQuery sortable elements depending on their attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have couple of containers on page that are `.sortable()` therefore all elements inside that `<div>` can be moved around from one container to another, back and forth using `connectWith` option. But, how can I prevent some of those elements to be dropped on specific sortable columns?

Each element have some specific attribute that describes me on which `.sortable()` container can be moved.

Comment: One of the options is to do some validation e.g. in the http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive property.

Comment: Yes, thats right ! I can validate a dropped element upon container has received specific item, and if it does not meet the requirement, can trigger a `$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');`. Thank you for a hint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you may specify the possible targets of the sortable drop areas:

> **[connectWith](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith)**
>
> Type: Selector
>
> Default: false
>
> A selector of other sortable elements that the items from this list
>   should be connected to. This is a one-way relationship, if you want
>   the items to be connected in both directions, the connectWith option
>   must be set on both sortable elements. Code examples: Initialize the
>   sortable with the connectWith option specified:
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).sortable({
>   connectWith: "#shopping-cart"
> });
> ```
>
> Get or set the connectWith option, after initialization:
>
> ```
> // Getter
> var connectWith = $( ".selector" ).sortable( "option", "connectWith" );
>
> // Setter
> $( ".selector" ).sortable( "option", "connectWith", "#shopping-cart" );
> ```

For more precision use something like: api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive